# Not able to open topcoder arena in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I installed the required jdk and icedtea application in ubuntu 14.04.

Then I ran the following command  :

> javaws http://www.topcoder.com/contest/arena/ContestAppletProd.jnlp

The icedtea application is opening but is stuck in the loading part. What should I do?

Comment: I guess is some networking problem. Are you sure there aren't any firewalls or something...?

Comment: Actually, I tried now and I also cannot access the arena. Maybe try again later?

Comment: No, there aren't any firewalls/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you have a good internet connection. As soon as you see the iced tea image on your screen, open google chrome. You will see a downloading dialog box at the right bottom of your screen. Let it complete downloading. Then, iced tea will continue and you will get to work on topcoder.